# Cannot get 'match-hidden-files' to work

Tags: bash, autocomplete, dot-files

I have been trying to get 'match-hidden-files' to work on bash 4.3.11, but I can't. I wanted to make sure it's not something I'm doing wrong.

```
$ grep match-hidden-files .inputrc 
set match-hidden-files on
```

Here are example folders:

```
$ ls -ld .icon*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 victor victor   57 Oct 20 10:39 .icons -> /home/victor/Sync/BitTorrentSync/victor/ConfigFiles/icons
drwxrwxr-x 2 victor victor 4096 Nov  2 00:14 .icons2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 victor victor    0 Nov  2 00:55 .icons3
drwxrwxr-x 2 victor victor 4096 Nov  2 00:59 .icons4
```

When I type 'cd ico' (without the '.') and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> nothing happens. I would expect to see this:

```
$ ls .ico
.icons/  .icons2/ .icons3  .icons4
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect to see `cd ico`<kbd>Tab</kbd> to match anything starting with `.` as you already gave the beginning of the filename yourself.

The man page is not very explicit:

```
match-hidden-files (On)
       This variable, when set to On, causes readline to  match  files
       whose  names  begin  with  a `.' (hidden files) when performing
       filename completion.  If set to Off, the leading  `.'  must  be
       supplied by the user in the filename to be completed.
```

If you do `ls`<kbd>Tab</kbd> and you have `set match-hidden-files on` (the default) it will change to `ls .icons` on the first <kbd>Tab</kbd> and to:

```
$ ls .icons
.icons/  .icons2/ .icons3  .icons4/
```

on the second <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and if you have set it to `off` it will not.

**Once you start with `ls ico` it will not retroactively put the dot before the `i`, whatever the value of `match-hidden-files`.**

Please note that you need to start a new `bash` to check any changes to `~/.inputrc`, it is not re-read for new commands. As indicated `match-hidden-files` default is `on`, so you do not need to set it explicitly.

Comment: Got it... thanks for the explanation. I had read the man page and that second part is very misleading:

"If set to Off, the leading  `.'  must  be supplied by the user in the filename to be completed." 

But I did a few tests and saw what you explained. Thanks.